# How to allocate subsequent variables based on value of previous variables in pulp python?

Tags: python, optimization, pulp, mixed-integer-programming

I am solving an optimization problem in python using pulp library. I have a 5X5 matrix as a decision variables (x(i,j)) for an optimization problem. These decision variables can take integer values from 1 to 10. I need help in writing code for 2 constraints that I couldn't define in pulp:

1. If value of x(i,j) is 1, then value of x(i,k)=1 for k >j (this constraint means that in any row if value of a decision variable is 1, then value of all subsequent elements in that row is also 1)
2. If value of x(i,j) is not 1, and value of x(i,k) is not 1, then x(i,j) should not be equal to x(i,k) ( this constraint means that in any row no 2 elements (values not equal to 1) can be equal

I am also attaching a screenshot of a sample x matrix that satisfies these 2 constraints. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fU72T.png)

Comment: Things will be much easier if you use a binary variable `x(i,j,k) = 1 if element (i,j) has value k`.

Answer (score 0):

Building on @Erwin Kalvelagen's comment, if the decision variables are chosen as binary variables:

`y(i,j,k) == 1`, iff element `(i, j)` has value `k`

Then your 2nd constraint is very straightforward (assuming `set_I` and `set_J` and `set_K` have been declared as the appropriate lists):

```
for i in set_I:
    for k in set_K:
        if k==1:
            continue
        model += lpSum([y[i, j, k] for j in set_J]) <= 1
```

In other words for each row `i`, and all possible numbers `k` (except `1`) they can appear in at most 1 column of each row.

The first constraint is a little more interesting, and I'm sure it could be done in lots of different ways. Here is one approach - we want to forbid all numbers (except `1`) which have at least one `1` to their left. So we can set constraints as follows:

```
for i in set_I:
    for j in set_J:
        if j == 1:
            continue # no constraint for 1st column
        for k in set_K:
            if k==1:
                continue # no constraint on 1s
            prev_cols = [item for item in set_J if item < j]
            model += y[i, j, k] <= 1 - 0.25*lpSum([y[i, item, 1] for item in prev_cols])
```

You might need to change some `1`'s to `0`'s depending on exactly how you've set up your indexing / sets. To understand this last constraint consider two cases:

i) None of the previous columns have `1`s in them. This constraint will them become `y[i,j,k] <= 1` so it has no effect (`y` are binary variables anyway).

ii) Any of the previous columns have `1`s in them - constraint will become `y[i,j,k] <= 0.75` (or `0.5`, `0.25`, or `0` if there are 2, 3, or 4 previous ones). As `y` are binary variables the only feasible value less than `1` is `0`. So all non-`1` values will be forbidden for columns which have a `1` to the left of them.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this slightly differently. Again, using `x(i,j,k)=1` to indicate that cell `(i,j)` has value `k`:

```
 sum(k, x(i,j,k)) = 1        ∀i,j    # each cell contains exactly one value
 x(i,j,1) >= x(i,j-1,1)      ∀i,j>1  # x(i,j)=1 => x(i,j+1)=1
 sum(j, x(i,j,k)) <= 1       ∀i,k>1  # only one of 2,3,.. in a row
 x(i,j,k) ∈ {0,1}
```